# How can I find out how many individuals are inputted onto our civi system

Tags: civireport

I need to know how many families and individuals we work with each year. How can civi tell me these figures?

Comment: Hi Georgina, Samuel's answer is indeed the easiest way, however, I wonder if you what you want to know is how many contacts in your database did you work with in a given year - if so and if you record activities, you should be able to use one of the activity reports to come up with this information - please confirm whether this was your intent and I would be happy to provide you with a more specific response. Kind regards, Tamar

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way :

- menu Search -> Find Contacts
- is `- any contact type -` -> replace by the contact type you want to count (Household or Individual)
- click `Search` button

In the result, you will see the total count (here 1238 individual contacts) :

[image]

You can use another search to have more criteria and get the total count for each. The search result will always show you the total count.